# Why I can still use $ in a page that's not having jQuery loaded?

Tags: javascript

I am just on http://example.com - literally the reserved example domain.

I opened the console and typed `$('body')↙`

I got this:

[image: dollar-sign]

I am pretty sure this page has NO jquery loaded. To make sure it has nothing to do with my Chrome extensions, I tried Safari, Opera, and Firefox. All got the same results. Why the dollar sign still works? Is the `$` a new JavaScript native function now?

Comment: It's only a method in the Chrome console that returns the first element matching a selector.

Answer (score 5):

All Chromium-based browsers (Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge, etc) have a set of utility functions in the Developer Tools console window - [this includes `$()` as an alias of `querySelector`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities#queryselector), which has the same name as jQuery's `$` (`jQuery`) object.

They are documented here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities

```
$_
$0
$1
$2
$3
$4
$
$$
$x
clear
copy
debug
dir
dirxml
inspect
getEventListeners
keys
monitor
monitorEvents
profile
queryObjects
table
undebug
unmonitor
unmonitorEvents
values
```

- Note that these utility functions cannot be used from page scripts (`<script>`): they can only be used in the Developer Tools console.
- If a page *does* include a function with the same name as a Developer Tools utility function then the page's functions take precedence over the utility functions

  - So if a page uses jQuery, then `$` will be jQuery's, not Chrome's.

This is not the same as the `console.` API, like `console.log`, `console.error`, etc, which are part of the browser API.